# How to improve this Python challenge answer? (arrays, slice)

Tags: python, arrays, slice

The challenge was described as: you have an array A of length N with integers, in this array we want to find the first element of the pair of elements that have the highest difference, e.g. given A = [1,2,5,6] the first element would be 2, or A[1], because 5-2=3.

More formally, the first element of the pair is P, the second pair is Q, and 0<P<Q. The sequence order matters. There were some more paraphrases of essentially the same info that I can't recall.

My quick solution that scored rather low:

```
def solution(A):
    candidate = 0
    saved_diff = 0
    for elems in range(0, len(A)-1):
        if A[elems] < A[elems+1]:
            diff = A[elems+1] - A[elems]
            if diff > saved_diff:
                candidate = elems
                saved_diff = diff
    return candidate
```

I am curious how this can be improved? Should I have considered finding all possible pairs with the same difference? Is the calculation inefficient? Am I not covering some specific edge cases?

Comment: What? Are you trying to find two elements, such that their distance (absolute value, difference, whatever) is maximized? So for `A = [-1, 5, 6, 2, 3]`, would the answer be `6- (-1) = 7`?

Comment: Can you give me the source of this problem / the original problem statement, please?

Comment: They asked to find the pair in the sequence that has the biggest difference as in Q-P is maximal. I can't provide the original statement since this was a coding test.

Comment: OK. Please confirm the answer i provided in my example is correct, and I will write you an answer.

Comment: No, you are looking to maximize difference, but you are disregarding the sequence order. The order matters.

Comment: I see. So you want two consecutive elements that have the largest difference? So in my example, the answer would be `6` because of elements `-1 and 5`?

Comment: The formal statement does not imply that `Q = P + 1`. If that were the case, a trivial O(N) solution would suffice. With `P < Q` more generally, the naive solution would be O(N^2), but using dynamic programming you can still (I think) achieve O(N) time.

Comment: Put another way, you scored low because I don't think you are solving the problem they asked you to solve.

Comment: @chepner I don't even think we need dynamic programming. I don't think the `O(N)` idea (at least the one I'm thinking of) constitutes as dynamic programming, more like running min/max.

Comment: Also, why is nobody else asking for the original statement / link? That'd make things so much easier.

Comment: @chepner It isn't clear from the description if P and Q are the indexes or values. They're probably values because otherwise the condition `P > 0` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @interjay It does if it's the constraint that ensures `P` is a valid index into the array.

Comment: @chepner But 0 is a valid index. So P and Q are probably values and not indexes as you are assuming.

Comment: Not if the problem description talks about an array with indices 1 through N instead of 0 through N-1. This is why we need the original problem statement.

Comment: @interjay Not to interj-ect, but doesn't that show P and Q are probably indexes...?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. This is what i mean; OP said "first element of the pair is P", implying `P` is an element. However, something like `0<P<Q` looks rather strange (and out of place; why not 0 < a[i]?) and is maybe a typo for `0 <= P <= Q <= N-1` or `0<P<Q<N`. There's just so much not clear about the question. I'm choosing to flag it.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is unordered I believe you have found the best solution because you have to check each number and its O(n).

The only thing `if A[elems] < A[elems+1]:` does not seem necessary to me.

if the list is ordered you have to check right to left and:
`if L[x]-L[X-1] > L[X-2]` (where `X in range(len(L)[::-1]`) you can stop searching because you can't possibly find a bigger number.

(if you have negative numbers the logic is the same but you have to slightly change the check)

Probably there are even better optimizations but my math is not that good.

Cool problem tho, it made me think, thanks :)

Comment: Why are people answering when it's not even clear what OP is asking? Why is this answer getting upvoted??

Comment: @RyanZhang I believe that this answer is general enough, yes he was really vague but I can't think about any other possible formulation of the problem, either the list is ordered or is not ordered, whether or not there are negative numbers doesn't really matter

Comment: We don't even know said "scoring" that made him score low... what if OP is doing code golf? What if OP wants the *slowest* code? Too many details are missing to provide an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: k, you are trolling.

Comment: Don't dismiss my reply as "trolling". I'm providing examples to prove a point: when the question isn't clear enough, [we should not provide an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266426/is-it-ok-to-answer-vague-unclear-questions). There is too much to clarify.